# New dataframe with sums based on conditions of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, conditional-statements

I have a question regarding dataframe manipulation. 
I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
year | month | deviceCategoy  | sessions

2017 | 4     | desktop        | 140000

2017 | 4     | mobile         | 200000

2017 | 4     | tablet         | 80000

...   ...       ...             ...
```

All in all the dataframe contains data for the whole year 2017 and 2018 until now. 
Now I want to have a new dataframe, where I only have the device categories desktop and mobile. The sessions for the tablets should be added to desktop.

The result should look like this:

```
year | month | deviceCategoy  | sessions

2017 | 4     | desktop        | 220000

2017 | 4     | mobile         | 200000
```

Does anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: Can u show the expected output.  Try `i1 < df1$deviceCategory == "tablet"; df1$deviceCategory[i1] <- "desktop"; aggregate(sessions ~ year + deviceCategory, df1, sum)`

Comment: I added the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could change the "tablet" strings to "desktop" and then do an `aggregate`

```
i1 <- df1$deviceCategoy == "tablet"
df1$deviceCategoy[i1] <- "desktop"
aggregate(sessions ~ ., df1, sum)
#   year month deviceCategoy sessions
#1 2017     4       desktop   220000
#2 2017     4        mobile   200000
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(deviceCategoy = replace(deviceCategoy, deviceCategoy == "tablet", "desktop")) %>%
   group_by_at(names(.)[1:3]) %>% 
   summarise(sessions = sum(sessions))
```